# Is there a way to work with arrays and use Protege

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, protege

I am trying to perform the functions on arrays such as inverse of and transpose on matrices and use it along with Protege so as to calculate the forces and deflections using reasoner. We can perform the calculations using SWRL rules in ontology but it does not support array as data type. But we have Postgres and MongoDB which supports arrays. Is there any way to work with arrays and use inverse operation in ontology? Suppose inverse operation is done by database such as Postgres then how to display the array elements in ontology? Can MongoDB be used here? If yes how do we connect to Protege 5.2. I understand WebProtege can be used along MongoDB but the current version of WebProtege does not support reasoning part. Also Ontop plugin does not support connectivity with MongoDB. Kindly clarify if I am missing some thing in meeting the objective of working with arrays in ontology.